# I am a Kalinga Shrauta Brahmin and I know that my family belongs to Gautama Gotra and Kauthuma Shakha of Samaveda. What is my pravara then?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins, gotra

I am from Bhubaneswar, Odisha. I know that my family belongs to Kauthuma Shakha of Samaveda and follows the Latyayana Sutra. However my father doesn't exactly remember the pravara.

Comment: Best way is to look in the latyayana Grhya sutra you will find the link. Meanwhile http://brahminrituals.blogspot.com/2018/05/number-of-more-than-400-brahmin-gothras.html

Answer (score 3):

Gautam , Angiras , Utathya  .

I'm also from Gautam gotra and follow Samveda .

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Answers posted here must be backed up by authentic sources. To learn more visit [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) . Also feel free to visit chatroom if you need any help: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism